# Modem Manager crashing in 12.10

Tags: modem-manager

When I start Ubuntu 12.10, I see the message **"System Program Problem..."**
Modem Manager crashes and I can't view any web page.
I downloaded the latest modem-manager from ubuntu updates, but it also doesn't work.
**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes I've had the same problem after update 12.10 (worked fine with 12.04). 
My Solution downgrade modem-manager (to deb of 12.04)

download deb:
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/98148171/modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb 
from (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/modemmanager/0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2)

and the install the old version:

```
sudo dpkg -i modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

to prevent update to version 0.6.x lock the version in synaptic.
After downgrade I got the question for PIN immediately.

NOTE: Give ubuntu a change to repair, so keep in touch of update of 0.6.x version ;-)